# Worst Case Binary Search?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

The question is:

> In order to distinguish ordinary emails from spam,
>   an algorithm with several features has been designed. Every feature provides
>   information about the message, for instance number of suspicious words, the
>   length of the message, degree of matching with spam templates etc. Every feature is a discrete variable with two values, for example, low/high, short/long, and similar/dissimilar. A tree with 255 nodes has been employed to make the decision whether to reject an email. How many operations/steps/time units
>   are required **at most** to process each email?

I was thinking that this would be a perfect binary tree, so 2^n - 1 = 255, thus n = 8. However, I was starting to consider the following "worst-case" scenario:

```
...O
../\
.O..O
..../\
...O..O
and so forth.
```

So would this use a binary search recurrence relation. T(n)=T(n/2)+1?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have the right answer Jay. From the question, I would draw the tree to look like this:

```
>                     o
>                    /\
> feature 1:        o  o
>                  /\  /\
> feature 2:      o  o o o
> 
                   ...
```

So you start with a root value. Then you ask if the feature has been successfully met by the email or not, so it breaks into 2 nodes, Y or N. For Y (left-subtree), you ask if the email has met the 2nd feature, Y or N and this breaks off into 2 more node and the same is repeated on the N side (right-subtree). Repeat for all features.

We know that the big-Omega (worst case) for a perfect binary tree is log(n) [base 2]. So log(255) [base 2] is approximately 8, & that must be the max number of steps required.

Answer (score 0):

If your tree is a balanced binary tree, then the answer would be 8.

The wording of the problem doesn't seem to call that out though. So that being said, we could make a tree that is a chain (only right children), which would make 255 the worse case.